# Regex,Php - find correct names with random numbers in string

Tags: php, regex

Hi i would like to find every string what contains this

```
SET_X_GAME_X_SCORE
```

Where `X` is a random number.

I tried something like this

```
/^SET_[0-9]_GAME_[0-9]_SCORE(.*)/
```

but it didn't work.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Add quantifiers `"/^SET_[0-9]+_GAME_[0-9]+_SCORE(.*)/"`. BTW, how exactly didn't it work?

Comment: Can you show your PHP usage and sample string?

Comment: Contains or begins with?

Answer (score 1):

> Hi i would like to find every string what contains this

If you really mean *"contains"* then you should stop using the `^` that means *begin with*

```
"/SET_[0-9]+_GAME_[0-9]+_SCORE(.*)/"
```

also a few sample rows within the question would be useful